# Выбор значения в одном input, в зависимости от введенного в другом inpute.JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Пример.

Корректировка такая:

- Ввожу значение <0.23  в другой инпут выводит 1.4
- Ввожу значение <0.33  в другой инпут выводит 1.6
- Ввожу значение <0.43  в другой инпут выводит 1.8
- Ввожу значение <0.53  в другой инпут выводит 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one'),
    two = document.getElementById('two'),
    res;

one.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var n = one.value;

  if (n < .23) { res = 1.4; } 
  else if (n < .33) { res = 1.6; } 
  else if (n < .43) { res = 1.8; } 
  else if (n < .53) { res = 2; }
  else { res = 'out of range'; }
  
  two.value = res;
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="one" />
<input id="two" />
```

Comment: Благодарю тебя.

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом задача решается так: https://jsfiddle.net/0439r4js/

```
elem1.oninput = function() {
    var val = document.getElementById('elem1').value;
    document.getElementById('str').innerHTML="Вы ввели: "+val*0.3;
};
```

Только в примере я любое значение умножаю на 0.3, а вы if добавьте и можетее умножить или разделить на то что вам надо.

Comment: Мне нужно если значение меньше 0.33,то в  инпут выводит 1.6, или если значение меньше  больше 0.33 то выводит 2, вычислений тут нет.

Comment: Ну тогда innerHTML="Вы ввели: "+" 0.33"; например а if сами сделаете